# Android Studio - Firestore WatchStream - How to collect status code from WatchStream Object

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

Upon a button click, I collect data from the firestore. However, I'm trying to find a way to determine if there was an issue reaching the server, such as lack of internet connection. I attempted to use the onFailureListener, but later realized that the callback is only called when there is an exception - so it's not called if there isn't a internet connection. After some testing without WiFi or data turned on, I got lucky and ended up finding a nice debug line added in by the developers.

> W/Firestore: (22.0.0) [WatchStream]: (3dbde8d) Stream closed with
> status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host
> firestore.googleapis.com, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
> "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname

I did find that there is a WatchStream object in Android Studio, but I have no idea how to use it. Searching google only brought up items related to watching streams. I even tried searching for "WatchStream" on the firebase page, but nothing there either. I'm just looking to collect the same status information as what is shown to me in the debug line.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.